# Rsync between two VM stalls after few files

Tags: virtual-machine, rsync

I have two VM (let's say VM A and B) on the same host. I try to `rsync` between those VM, from VM B (with a rsync daemon running on A):

```
B$ rsync -rvut user@A::src dest/
```

It works well during few seconds, copies several files, then suddenly it just stalls (or slows down, from several MB/s to few kB/s). If I kill the process, then relaunch the `rsync` command, it's okay for several files then stalls again.

I think it is an IO load issue (same host), and I wonder if I can do something (using `nice`, `ionice` or something like that) to adjust IO load to avoid resuming sync every 10s.

Thank you

**EDIT**

There is some logs:

```
[...]

recv_files(pdf/dir1/file1b.pdf)
pdf/dir1/file1b.pdf
data recv 32768 at 0
data recv 32768 at 32768
data recv 32768 at 65536
data recv 32768 at 98304
data recv 32768 at 131072
data recv 22278 at 163840
      186118 100%  550.78kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#51, to-check=89/102979)
got file_sum
set modtime of pdf/dir1/.file1b.pdf.SYo81u to (1387400862) Wed Dec 18 22:07:42 2013
renaming pdf/dir1/.file1b.pdf.SYo81u to pdf/dir1/file1b.pdf
touch_up_dirs: pdf/dir1 (9719)
set modtime of pdf/dir1 to (1387400873) Wed Dec 18 22:07:53 2013
recv_files(pdf/dir2)
recv_files(pdf/dir2/file2a.pdf)
pdf/dir2/file2a.pdf
           0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
data recv 32768 at 0
data recv 32768 at 32768
       65536  36%   56.69kB/s    0:00:01  
data recv 32768 at 65536
       98304  55%   34.30kB/s    0:00:02  
data recv 32768 at 98304
      131072  73%   27.88kB/s    0:00:01  
data recv 32768 at 131072
data recv 14216 at 163840
      178056 100%   37.87kB/s    0:00:04 (xfer#52, to-check=88/102979)
got file_sum
set modtime of pdf/dir2/.file2a.pdf.A1lhL9 to (1387404392) Wed Dec 18 23:06:32 2013
renaming pdf/dir2/.file2a.pdf.A1lhL9 to pdf/dir2/file2a.pdf
recv_files(pdf/dir2/file2b.pdf)
pdf/dir2/file2b.pdf
           0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
data recv 32768 at 0
       32768  51%    2.84kB/s    0:00:10  
data recv 30261 at 32768
       63029 100%    5.46kB/s    0:00:11 (xfer#53, to-check=87/102979)
got file_sum
set modtime of pdf/dir2/.file2b.pdf.wx2GN3 to (1387404395) Wed Dec 18 23:06:35 2013
renaming pdf/dir2/.file2b.pdf.wx2GN3 to pdf/dir2/file2b.pdf
recv_files(pdf/dir2/file2c.pdf)
pdf/dir2/file2c.pdf
           0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
data recv 32768 at 0
       32768  17%    0.34kB/s    0:07:37  
data recv 32768 at 32768
       65536  35%    0.20kB/s    0:09:53  
data recv 32768 at 65536
   98304  52%    0.17kB/s    0:08:27  
data recv 32768 at 98304
      131072  70%    0.16kB/s    0:05:41  
data recv 32768 at 131072
      163840  88%    0.16kB/s    0:02:22  
data recv 22231 at 163840
      186071 100%    0.20kB/s    0:15:14 (xfer#54, to-check=86/102979)
got file_sum
set modtime of pdf/dir2/.file2c.pdf.BrJJSL to (1387404392) Wed Dec 18 23:06:32 2013
renaming pdf/dir2/.file2c.pdf.BrJJSL to pdf/dir2/file2c.pdf
touch_up_dirs: pdf/dir2 (9720)
recv_files(pdf/dir3)
recv_files(pdf/dir3/file3.pdf)
set modtime of pdf/dir2 to (1387404395) Wed Dec 18 23:06:35 2013
pdf/dir3/file3.pdf
           0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
data recv 32768 at 0
data recv 32768 at 32768
data recv 32768 at 65536
data recv 32768 at 98304
data recv 32768 at 131072
data recv 14240 at 163840
      178080 100%   15.44MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#55, to-check=85/102979)
```

As you can see in this log, sync went slower and slower, it was almost stalled. This time, I did not kill it. It took 15 minutes to copy `file2c.pdf` (182 kB), then it restart copying `file3.pdf` in less than a second...

Comment: enable log verbose to find out more

Comment: I enabled --log-file, but I can't get any useful information in the log file. How could I get more verbose log?

Comment: with appending more than one "v" it becomes more verbose

Comment: I knew about this for ssh, but ignored that worked for rsync too. Thanks. I edited the post with more log.